# How to fire an event on uninstallation of an iphone app?

Tags: ios

On uninstallation of an iphone app.I want to delete all the data from my database serve

Comment: When user delete application it removes all data from it, except backup on server or Mac OS.

Answer (score 1):

this can be possible but I dont think there is a very simple way like implementing a method when user removes your app. you can take a look in [APNS Feedback Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3) , this might help you.

> If a provider attempts to deliver a push notification to an
>   application, but the application no longer exists on the device, the
>   device reports that fact to Apple Push Notification Service. This
>   situation often happens when the user has uninstalled the application.
>   If a device reports failed-delivery attempts for an application, APNs
>   needs some way to inform the provider so that it can refrain from
>   sending notifications to that device. Doing this reduces unnecessary
>   message overhead and improves overall system performance.

Comment: It says " If a device reports failed-delivery attempts for an application, APNs needs some way to inform the provider". That means only if a push notification fails, it will get to know that user uninstalled. That kind of behavior is possible only with push notification. He might have to implement push notification only for this uninstall feature even if that wont serve any other purpose to him.

Answer (score 0):

For an iOS app, remove option which comes after long pressing on icon is the only 'uninstalling' option which will always remove any stored date of the app from device. There will not be any particular event triggered when user does that.